# Div not displaying output which is made hidden by default in css

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is the java script function.I want it to make the div "resultss" visible and show the output.

But it's not displaying results, php code is executed without errors. Whys is this not displaying any output.

I'm trying to append the results at the bottom of same page where user submits some data

```
<script>
function myFunction()
    {
    var e = document.getElementById("resultss");
    e.style.display = "block";
    <?php

    $format =  $_SESSION["ff"];
    $ses_id = $_SESSION["id"];
    $filena = $_SESSION["filename"];
    //$pubquery = $_SESSION["pubquery"];
    $result1 = shell_exec("C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\PredictoR\Model_desc.py $format $ses_id $filena  2>&1");
    $properties = explode(" ", $result1);
    if($properties[0] == 1)
    {
    $property = "Substrate";
    } else  {
    $property = "Non-substrate";
    }
    $molwt = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $properties[1]));
    $nhd = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $properties[2]));
    $nha = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $properties[3]));
    $logp = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $properties[4]));

    ?>

    var molwt = <?php echo json_encode( $molwt); ?>;
    var nhd = <?php echo json_encode( $nhd); ?>;
    var nha = <?php echo json_encode( $nha); ?>;
    var logp = <?php echo json_encode( $logp); ?>;
    var property = <?php echo json_encode( $property); ?>;

    document.getElementById('properties').innerHTML="Molecule is : "+property+"  \n\
    <br/>Molecular weight is : "+molwt+" \n\
    <br/>No. of hydrogen bond donors = "+nhd+"\n\
    <br/>No. of hydrogen bond acceptors = "+nha+"\n\
    <br/>Log P :  = "+logp+";

    }
</script>
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, I can't see you have assigned any value to the "resultss" div.

Comment: Try `e.setAttribute("visibility","visible");"`

Comment: @Nirmal I've assigned values to properties which is child element of resultss

Answer (score 0):

Put that PHP code outside javascript function in seperate DIV with id and make this display = none at first then when your showing result call the javascript and you can use display = block or display = inline-block or display = flex (New in CSS3). to make your DIV visible.